# Linux detach from process after certain string

Tags: linux, bash

So, I have a command which starts a webserver, it goes step by step and puts output to standard output. It goes like:

```
step 1...
step 2...
step 3...
server up and running on port 9000
```

However, this gets stuck waiting user input (this is typesafe activator) and when launched from command line doesn't finish. How do I detach from this script waiting for user input and let it run, but continue with the parent shell? I want to detach as soon as I see that server is running.

Comment: Can you show the command line you're executing (per [ask])?

Comment: ./activator
Does it really matter? I want to grep it's output and stop detach on certain regex

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: When the server is running, type `Ctrl+Z` and `bg`. `Ctrl+Z` will pause the process execution and `bg` will send the process to the background releasing the shell for new user input. **Warn:** your server is tied to the running shell. If you logout from that shell the server will be killed.

Option #2: Launch your script with `nohup`, which will run your script detached from the terminal. Example: `nohup ./activator`.

Option #3: Launch your script inside a `screen` session and then detach from the session via `Ctrl+d`.